spring boot extension pack on vsc not charge the gradle.properties on application.properties on win10. how I do that?
I'm using windows 10 using spring tool suite on visual studio code and gradle for spring boot with java.
When I run gradel build or gradelw build.
It's construct well and charge the gradle.properties on application.properties but in the folder build and spring tool suit de automatic construct on bin, and application.properties not well charged and when I run with spring boot extension pack I have an error.
  .   ____          _            __ _ _   
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \  
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \ 
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / / 
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/  
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.5)

2024-05-11T13:55:15.300+02:00  INFO 28648 --- [person] [  restartedMain] c.s.erp.person.api.PersonApplication     : Starting PersonApplication using Java 21.0.3 with PID 28648 (D:\SoftwareSprouting-code\ERP\personApi\bin\main started by ezequ in D:\SoftwareSprouting-code\ERP\personApi)
2024-05-11T13:55:15.304+02:00  INFO 28648 --- [person] [  restartedMain] c.s.erp.person.api.PersonApplication     : No active profile 
set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-05-11T13:55:15.398+02:00  INFO 28648 --- [person] [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property 
defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2024-05-11T13:55:15.399+02:00  INFO 28648 --- [person] [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2024-05-11T13:55:16.257+02:00  WARN 28648 --- [person] [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.R2dbcAutoConfiguration]: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$PoolConfiguration
2024-05-11T13:55:16.270+02:00  INFO 28648 --- [person] [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-05-11T13:55:16.313+02:00 ERROR 28648 --- [person] [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.R2dbcAutoConfiguration]: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$PoolConfiguration
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:544) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:321) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:246) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:534) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:746) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:743) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:714) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:183) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:416) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:788) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]       
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at com.softwaresprouting.erp.person.api.PersonApplication.main(PersonApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$PoolConfiguration
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:220) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:534) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'postgresqlHost' in value "r2dbc:postgresql://${postgresqlHost}:${postgresqlPort}/${postgresqlDatabase}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:230) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:80) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:61) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:552) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]  
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$PooledConnectionFactoryCondition.hasPoolUrl(ConnectionFactoryConfigurations.java:172) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$PooledConnectionFactoryCondition.getMatchOutcome(ConnectionFactoryConfigurations.java:156) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        ... 27 common frames omitted

I see the bin folder and is not charged the gradle.properties on application.properties.
my application.properties:
spring.application.name=person
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:postgresql://${postgresqlHost}:${postgresqlPort}/${postgresqlDatabase}
spring.r2dbc.username=${postgresqlUsername}
spring.r2dbc.password=${postgresqlPassword} 

my gradle.properties:
#postgresql
postgresqlHost=127.0.0.1
postgresqlPort=5432
postgresqlDatabase=person
postgresqlUsername=person
postgresqlPassword=person123 

my build.gradle:
plugins {
        id 'java'
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.5'
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    }
    
    group = 'com.softwaresprouting.erp'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    
    java {
        sourceCompatibility = '21'
    }
    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
        runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
        runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
        testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    }
    
    tasks.named('test') {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
    
    processResources {
        expand(project.properties)
    }


can you point us at a sample project and a few steps how to reproduce this? Happy to take a look.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
Please see how to ask.
minimal reproducible example
